# dd without any options

Tags: linux, dd

What does dd command do when ran without any options ?

> ```
> [hannah@lenovo ~]$ dd
> ```

```
^C0+0 records in
0+0 records out
0 bytes copied, 7.71982 s, 0.0 kB/s
```

Does it delete any files or it's nothing to worry about ? Googling didn't help

Thanks in advance

Comment: Cross site duplicates: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/304583/what-happens-if-you-run-dd-without-any-argument and https://askubuntu.com/questions/1193280/does-dd-command-without-parameter-or-input-output-redirection-do-anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What does `dd` command do when ran without any options?

> The `dd` utility shall copy the specified input file to the specified output file with possible conversions using specific input and output block sizes. […]
>
> `if=file`
> Specify the input pathname; **the default is standard input**.
> `of=file`
> Specify the output pathname; **the default is standard output**.

<sup>([source](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/dd.html); emphasis mine)</sup>

Bare `dd` is like bare `cat`. The difference is in buffering: with `dd` you won't see lines printed right away. Still if you type something and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> (twice if needed) then `dd` will print it.

> Does it delete any files or it's nothing to worry about?

It doesn't. Nothing to worry about.